# Hide Options in Resco Mobile CRM

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-365

I wanted to hide Optionset values on Field Service - Dynamics 365 app. We are doing customizations using Woodford Solution. Based on Resco Javascript Bridge Reference, I see no methods to hide options in existing Option Set. So I created a ComboBox and tried to add Options into ComboBox. But it is showing only one single option even if I add multiple options that too with the wrong Label on ComboBox.

```js
if ((responseTypeOptionSetValues.length == responseTypeOptionSetLables.length)
      && responseTypeOptionSetLables.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < responseTypeOptionSetValues.length; i++) {
        if (valueListOptions.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < responseTypeOptionSetValues.length; i++) {
                if (valueListOptions.indexOf(responseTypeOptionSetValues[i].toString()) != -1) {
                    finalLabelValue = responseTypeOptionSetLables[i].toString();
                    finalOptionValue = responseTypeOptionSetValues[i].toString();
                    comboItem.listDataSource = {
                        **finalLabelValue: finalOptionValue,**
                                };
                }
            }
        }
    }                
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = new Object();

if ((responseTypeOptionSetValues.length == responseTypeOptionSetLables.length) && responseTypeOptionSetLables.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < responseTypeOptionSetValues.length; i++) {
        if (valueListOptions.indexOf(responseTypeOptionSetValues[i].toString()) != -1) {
            finalLabelValue = responseTypeOptionSetLables[i].toString();
            finalOptionValue = responseTypeOptionSetValues[i].toString();                      
            data[finalLabelValue] = finalOptionValue;
        }
    }
}
if (!isComboItemExists) {
    comboItem.listDataSource = data;
    detailView.insertItem(comboItem, -1);
}
else {
    comboItem.listDataSource = data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're nesting your loops with the same variable name.  Give each loop a unique variable: i, j, k...